# Humane speed mouse pointer & curved/different route towards endpoint

Tags: powershell

Good day all,

Thanks to former posts I've been able to make a use of shown small scripts that work properly with PowershellISE.

My question is, how do u make the mouse pointer go in a humane speed and direction go toward the next coordinates set in your script? Instead of instant clicks at the exact XY's stated? Plus how can u make a curved or randomized curved lines of mouse movement?

**For example:**

```
$x = (your number)
$y = (your number)
[System.Windows.Forms.Cursor]::Position = New-Object System.Drawing.Point($x, $y)
sleep -Seconds 01
$SendMouseClick::mouse_event(0x00000002, 0, 0, 0, 0);
$SendMouseClick::mouse_event(0x00000004, 0, 0, 0, 0);
```

If I set an $a & $b, then it has a new position to go to and I can copy the drawing point line and set it there. I just have no clue how to move from XY toward AB then in any other way than a straight line as shown in the next part under here which is a drag and drop test (also from posts on stackoverflow)..

```
[Win32]::SetCursorPos(25, 25);

$SendMouseClick::mouse_event(0x00000002, 0, 0, 0, 0);

for ($x = 0; $x -lt 50; $x+=5)
{
    [Win32]::SetCursorPos($x, $x);
    Start-Sleep -m 5
}

for ($x = 50; $x -lt 800; $x+=5)
{
    [Win32]::SetCursorPos($x, 50);
    Start-Sleep -m 5
}

$SendMouseClick::mouse_event(0x00000004, 0, 0, 0, 0);
```

Anyone that could help, any answers related to this subject and in a helpful/advising way, are highly appreciated.

Additional question, most likely a simplistic one, once the pointer/click script is executed outside of the powershell windows, how do I stop/break this script if its going over the same script continuously?

Kind regards,

A kind rookie /QuietPerson